# TabPage doesn't show WebBrowser Document Title

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a Form that contains a `button` and a `tabControl`. When clicked, the button calls the function `newTab()`.
This is the code for `newTab()`:

```
private void newTab(string url)
    {
        TabPage tp1 = new TabPage();
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tp1);
        WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();
        tp1.Controls.Add(wb1);
        wb1.Parent = tp1;
        wb1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        wb1.Navigate(url);
        tp1.Text = wb1.DocumentTitle;
        wb1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb1.DocumentTitleChanged += Wb1_DocumentTitleChanged;
    }
```

The problem is, when created, the webBrowser's DocumentTitle isn't shown. The name of the tab page remains blank. What can I do?
Tried `wb1.Document.Title` too, but it didn't work, either.

Comment: add the code that changes the tab text

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the title before it's done loading.  Use the DocumentCompleted event for that:

```
wb1.DocumentCompleted += wb1_DocumentCompleted;

void wb1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
  WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
  TabPage tb = wb.Parent as TabPage;
  if (tb != null) {
    tb.Text = wb.DocumentTitle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text in `DocumentTitleChanged`:

```
wb1.DocumentTitleChanged += (obj,args)=> tp1.Text = wb1.DocumentTitle;
wb1.Navigate(url);
```